# Typescript: Cannot find JQueryUI ... even though it can

Tags: typescript

I am trying to get started using `Typescript`, and am having a big problem with the definitions for `jQueryUI`. I have the `jqueryui.d.ts` from **DefinitelyTyped**. It lives in `/scripts/typings/jqueryui/jqueryui.d.ts` just fine.

I have a file, `documents.ts`, and at the top I have this line;

`///<reference path="~/Scripts/typings/jqueryui/jqueryui.d.ts"/>`

But still, I cannot use anything from it. I'm trying to use the `Resizable` widget;

`var resizable: JQueryUI.Resizable = $('selector').resizable({ ... });`

and I keep getting told "Cannot find JQueryUI". Is there anything I can do?

Comment: Do you get an error message like `error TS6053: File '~/Scripts/typings/jqueryui/jqueryui.d.ts' not found.`?

Comment: No. It clearly finds the file. It's green and everything. No squigglies.

Comment: Weird. It works for me unless I have the path wrong. I must be doing something different, but I cannot see what.

Answer (score 0):

The path to `jqueryui.d.ts` has to be relative to `document.ts`.

```
///<reference path="relative/path/to/typings/jqueryui/jqueryui.d.ts"/>
```

[[Spec](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/doc/spec.md#1111-source-files-dependencies)]

Comment: unfortunately, this did not turn out to be the problem. even worse, for some reason or another it suddenly is able to find the file now. I can't figure out why, I haven't made any changes.